# AddRange to a list within the same line?

Tags: c#, list, addrange

I want to add a range to the list but within the same line as initializing it, I am also just doing a normal add to the list within the same line.

**Previously was:**

```
List<Type> dto = new List<Type>();
dto.Add(sequence1);
dto.AddRange(sequence2); //sequence2 is also a list
```

**What I currently have:**

```
List<Type> dto = new List<Type> {sequence1};
dto.AddRange(sequence2);
```

I want to be able to perform the AddRange in the same line, is this possible?

Comment: `List<Type> dto = new List<Type> {sequence1}.AddRange(sequence2);`

Comment: @TryingToImprove `AddRange` does not return list, it returns void

Comment: @TonyVitabile What an invaluable comment..

Comment: @wudzik I might be to quick then.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this?

```
List<Type> dto = new List<Type> (sequence2){sequence1};
```

It will initialize dto with `sequence2` and add `sequence1` to the end of collection

Comment: Just a note, and might not be an issue for JayH, but I think this will reverse the order. In the original code sample, `sequence1` came before the entries in `sequence2`. This line here will have the `sequence2` entries before `sequence1`.

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately, receiving  Sequence contains no elements which is odd. Thanks for the suggestion though, sure it will work for some people.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ `Concat` operator on the result of the constructor:

```
List<int> l1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
List<int> l2 = new List<int>() { 3, 4 };
List<int> r = new List<int>(l1).Concat(l2).ToList();
```

or if you are just initializing with single element `elem`, choose one of:

```
List<int> r = new List<int>() { elem }.Concat(l2).ToList();
List<int> r = new[] { elem }.Concat(l2).ToList();
List<int> r = Enumerable.Repeat(elem, 1).ToList();
```

**Note:** depending on the further use of the `r`, you can skip `ToList()` because `IEnumerable` might be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If it is really important then you could create a extension, which will make it fluent, but how come you only want it in a single line?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> l1 = new List<int>() { 3, 4 };
        List<int> l2 = new List<int>() { 5, 6 };

        var a = new List<int>() { 1, 2 }.FluentAddRange(l1).FluentAddRange(l2);
    }

}
public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<T> FluentAddRange<T>(this List<T> list, List<T> newList)
    {
        list.AddRange(newList);

        return list;
    }
}
```